# Как переименовать окно стороннего процесса python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, окно, psutil

```
import os
import psutil

PROCNAME = "notepad.exe"
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name() == PROCNAME:
        print("запущено") #Но нужно переименовать процесс
    else:
        print("это не тот процесс")
```

Не понимаю ту ли библиотеку я использовал и она ли мне нужна, но меня интересует можно ли переименовать название окна и/или процесса по совместительству и насколько это имеет смысл?

видел много ответов с использованием ctypes, есть ли способ проще? если нет, то как реализовать через него?

Answer (score 0):

Для переименования окна стороннего процесса можно использовать библиотеку ctypes. Эта библиотека предоставляет функции для взаимодействия с внешними библиотеками на уровне Си. В данном случае для переименования окна необходимо будет использовать функцию WinAPI SetWindowText.

Comment: на чужое приложение оно не сработает

Comment: я все таки попробую, но если не получится, то мне все еще нужна будет помощь форума, эта задача стала для меня буквально принципиальна.